# How to remove focus from the Infragistics ultragrid cell when clicking outside?

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an infragistics ultragrid control in a windows form. There is an 'Add New' button outside to insert new rows to the grid.

The problem I faced is, when I click the button outside the grid, while I'm editing a cell inside the grid, the cell doesn't lose focus. Because of this the edited new value is not updated to its underlying data source.

I need this cell to lose focus and update it's underlying data source, because the 'Add New' button creates a new row with this particular column having a default value which is calculated based on the previous row's edited value.

So any ideas on how to unfocus the ultragrid cell? This situation may apply to normal GridView also.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it, but, when you click outside the Grid, the cell terminates the input mode and this will update the underlying datasource. This is the normal behavior, unless you have the `UpdateMode` property set to `OnUpdate`. Could you check ?

Comment: Thanks @Steve. The value of 'UpdateMode' is set to 'OnCellChangeOrLostFocus'. The cell loses focus when clicking on another control except the 'Add New' button. This is a ToolStripButton.

Comment: Then is the @alhalama answer the good one.

Comment: Yes @alhalama solution works fine. I used `myUltraGrid.ActiveRow.Cells[0].Activate();`, which also worked. But the previous one is a better solution I guess.

Comment: @vibgy the approach that I suggested is the approach recommended by Infragistics and it will better handle if the ActiveRow is not a data row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your button is on a Toolbar, then the behavior you are seeing is expected because toolbars don't take focus.  If this is the case before performing your logic you can use the [PerformAction](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~PerformAction%28UltraGridAction%29.html) method of the grid and pass in UltraGridAction.CommitRow to force the row that was being editor to commit its updates.

For example:

```
this.ultraGrid1.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.CommitRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `myUltraGrid.ActiveRow.Cells[0].Activate();` which also works. But the solution by @alhalama is better one I guess.

Comment: This approach can cause a NullReferenceException if either the ActiveRow is null or if the ActiveRow is a GroupByRow.  Also it will change the active cell of the grid while the approach that I suggested doesn't.  If it is indeed a menu or toolbar that doesn't take focus, with the approach that I suggested you can press F2 to enter edit mode on the cell again.  If you do use this approach, the following check would make sure that you have a data row: if (this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow != null && this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.IsDataRow) {this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells[0].Activate();}